# on.click not working on class I added with .addclass

Tags: jquery, onclick, slidedown

I'm trying to use a jquery .click function on a class I've added to the same div on a previous .click. The new class is adding to the div correctly but my $( ".two" ).click(function() isn't running. My first $(".one").click(function) is working perfectly. I'm wondering if I'm using weird logic or if something is out of order. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {    
  $( ".one" ).click(function() {
   $('.adventurevideoviewmore').addClass('two');
   $( ".adventure2" ).slideDown( 1000, function() {
   });
 });

 $( ".two" ).click(function() {
  $( ".adventure3" ).slideDown( 1000, function() {
  });
 });

});

</script>
```

here's my HTML

```
 <div class="adventure2"></div>
 <div class="adventure3"></div>
 <div class="adventurevideoviewmore one" ><img src="images/homepage/viewmorebutton.png"/></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$('.two')` click function is running on `$(document).ready()`, but no elements exist with that class at that time so the function is not bound to anything. What you need to do is add a click handler to the element at the time you are adding the `.two` class at the end of the animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $( ".one" ).click(function() {
        $('.adventurevideoviewmore').addClass('two');
        $( ".adventure2" ).slideDown( 1000, function() {
            $( ".two" ).click(function() {
                $( ".adventure3" ).slideDown( 1000, function() {});
            });
        });            
    });
});
```

This may cause you headaches though since the user can still click the `.one` element and have the handler added again. It looks like you are trying to create a wizard of some kind. If so, I suggest taking a slightly different approach.

**HTML**

Wrap the adventure is some kind of container if it isn't already

```
<div class="adventure-wizard" data-step="1" data-last="3">
    <div class="adventure1"></div>
    <div class="adventure2"></div>
    <div class="adventure3"></div>
    <div class="adventurevideoviewmore"><img src="images/homepage/viewmorebutton.png"/></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

Maintain the state in data on the container instead of classes on elements. This allows your view more button to always use the same handler and increment the wizard along.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Setup the click event on the view more button to increment the step and
        // animate the appropriate adventure element until the last is reached
        $('.adventureviewmore').click(function () {
            var wizard = $(this).parent();
            var step = wizard.data('step');
            var last = wizard.data('last');

            // If the end is reached do nothing
            if (step === last)
                return;

            // Increment the step
            step++;

            // Animate the adventure for the next step
            $('.adventure' + step).slideDown(1000);

            // Store the step back on the wizard
            wizard.data('step', step);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use event delegation:

```
 $( "body" ).on('click', '.two', function() {
    $( ".adventure3" ).slideDown( 1000, function() {
 });
```

Comment: For an explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Thank you for this Milind Anantwar and thank you for the reference on the explanation Juan! I ended up adding a .delay to my code so .adventure3 slidedown wasn't triggered at the same time of the .adventure2 slidedown.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a .delay when I added my 2nd 'two' class so the .adventure3 slide wouldn't trigger at the same time. Huge thanks to @Milind Anantwar, @Alexander, and @juan Mendes!

```
<script>
$( ".one" ).click(function() {
  $( ".adventure2" ).slideDown( 1000, function() {
  });

 $(".adventurevideoviewmore").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
  $(this).addClass("two");
  next();
 });
});

$( "body" ).on('click', '.two', function() {
  $( ".adventure3" ).slideDown( 1000, function() {
  });
});
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle of the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/cbart7421/j4er8r91/3/

Comment: You shouldn't need that delay and instead should move the addition of the `.two` class inside the slideDown() callback function that is called when the animation completes. See http://jsfiddle.net/1Lvkmo2m/1/

Comment: oh wow! I can't believe I missed that! Thank you @musicfuel! I'm still a little new to stackoverflow. How do I give someone credit for the answer?